# what is the difference between flyway-core and flyway-database-xxx

Tags: flyway

I was trying to update the flyway-core version from 9 to 10, but when running the tests I got the following errors for Oracle and postgresql

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL 
15.4
```

and

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Oracle 19.3
```

but after adding `flyway-database-oracle` and `flyway-database-postgresql` the error went away, with version 9 I only needed flyway-core.

what are these two libraries? here are the links to the libraries [flyway-database-oracle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-database-oracle) and [flyway-database-postgresql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-database-postgresql)

cheers,

es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did some re-organisation as part of Flyway V10, this is described [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3780).